# Firestore Angular get all Collection names in a document

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve all collection names inside a document as I have multiple collections inside 1 document.

also, this code I am trying to return the name of this specific collection.
Not sure how to do that.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.foodCollection = this.afs.doc(this.item+this.document).collection(this.collectionName);
    this.foods = this.foodCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as food;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        const name = a;
        return { id, data, name};
      });
    }));
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want, for a given document, to get the list of all its sub-collections?

Comment: It is currently not possible to list subcollections from web and mobile clients using the provided SDK. You could do this from a backend though.

Comment: Yeah I wanted all the names of sub-collections inside a document. But if it isn't possible, that's fine.

Comment: Actually it is possible to get this list with the **server SDKs**, in particular the Cloud Firestore Node.js Client API. You can write a Cloud Function that lists the subcollections of a document and call it from your app. The following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166) gives all the details for writing such a Cloud Function (disclaimer, I'm the author).

Comment: You would then call this Cloud Function from you app with angularfire as explained [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md).